# Knockout.js and JayData, foreach binding with select not populating default option

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jaydata

I'm having trouble specifying the data binding to correctly set the default option based on the JayData entity.  Even though the `testcase.Category.Id` value is giving the correct value, the correct option is not selected.

Here is a simplified example that definitely illustrates this behavior:

**Javascript**

```
// Jaydata

$data.Entity.extend("$org.types.TestCase", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Name: { type: "string", required: true },
    Class: { type: "string", required: true },
    Category: { type: "$org.types.Category", required: true },

});

$data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Category", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Name: { type: "string", required: true },
    Value: { type: "int", required: true }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("$org.types.OrgContext", {
    TestCases: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.TestCase },
    Categories: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.Category }
});

var DB = new $org.types.OrgContext({ name: "webSql", databaseName: "Test"});

// Knockout

function TestViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.testcases = ko.observableArray([]);
    DB.TestCases.toArray(this.testcases);

    this.categories = ko.observableArray([]);
    DB.Categories.toArray(this.categories);
}

// jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: {data: testcases, as: 'testcase'}">
        <li>
            <div><b>Name: </b><input data-bind="value: testcase.Name" /></div>
            <div><b>Class: </b><input data-bind="value: testcase.Class" /></div>
            <div><b>Category: </b>
                <select data-bind="options: $root.categories, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: testcase.Category.Id">

                </select>
            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>
</body>
```

I have also tried this binding, which exhibits the same behavior:

```
data-bind="options: $root.categories, optionsText: 'Name', value: testcase.Category"
```

Here are the libraries I am including:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jaydata/jaydata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jaydata/jaydataproviders/SqLiteProvider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jaydata/jaydatamodules/knockout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
```

Comment: is testcase.Category.Id an observable ? you can check with the isObservable ko function

Comment: The testcase array is observable.  It's an array of entities, of which Category is a property.

Comment: I am not familiar with `jaydata`, but the basic concept [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/4gAfK/). Taking a look at [my intializations](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/2RmCJ/) in combination with your better understanding of jaydata may hint at the issue.

Comment: Did you include the jaydataa specific knockout library, mentioned under extended array on this page http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-use-jaydata-with-knockoutjs ?

Comment: @jiggle: Yes, question updated to show my included libraries

Comment: @Origineil: Your first example is exactly what I have done; I'm going to have to look into your second a little further, thanks!